# Google App Maker - autofill textbox depending on dropdown selected option from an external database

Tags: mysql, textbox, dropdown, autofill, google-app-maker

What I'm currently doing is that on the Property Editor of my dropdown widget, on the Event Section using the `onValueEdit` function,  I'm trying to create a custom action script which will give a value to my textbox (using **widget.root.descendants.NameOfMyTextbox.value**) depending on the selected value of my dropdown.

The values of my dropdown are the IDs stored in my MySql database table **Process**, for example: `ID = 1, name = Assembly, manager = George`. For the textbox, I would like to get another table field value depending on the selected value of my dropdown through a **select** statement (like getting the manager value). What kind of app maker queries or functions should be useful in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dropdown option binding is `@datasources.Process.items` then your `onValueEdit` event simply needs to be:

```
widget.root.descendants.NameOfMyTextbox.value = newValue.manager;
```

This would be the only way to set this up however, because this way the options are pointing to your entire record in the Process table and upon selection you can get any other field from that record using `newValue.YourField`.

Comment: For my dropdown option binding, I use `@datasources.SGC.items..id_process` , in which the double dots `..` are projections for id_process. My current model name is **SGC** and is based on the JDBC SQL sample, using an external MySql database. I tried using the code you posted, but nothing happened.

Comment: Try just using `@datasources.SGC.items` instead of `..id_process` at the end. Usually your options give you the entries in your first field of the datasource, but in that case it still points to the record as a whole vs just the record field value. If for some reason with `@datasources.SGC.items` does not list your id_process field value then still use `@datasources.SGC.items` as your options but change your names options to `@datasources.SGC.items..id_process`. Hope that makes sense. Using the projection `..id_process` in options will only point to values not the record.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked changing the data binding in the options section to `@datasources.SGC.items`. Just a question, in my case I'm using `@datasources.SGC.items..name_process` in the names options to be displayed, if I want to get the values as id_process, should I change the *value options* data binding to `@datasources.SGC.item.id_process` or just keeping it as `@datasources.SGC.item`?

Comment: @John if you need access to any other field in you SGC datasource, then the options always have to be `@datasources.SGC.items` in the options. You can change your names property to anything you want as far as a description goes, either `@datasources.SGC.items..id_process` or `@datasources.SGC.items..name_process`. You can even go more complicated by doing something like this in the names property `(@datasources.items..id_process).map(function(id, i) {return id + ' -  ' + @datasources.items..name_process[i];})`.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Appreciate your help.